# Как поменять текст "выбрать опцию " для вариативного товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

wp+woo тема storefront. Как поменять текст "выбрать опцию" в карточке товара?
Если бы была одна опция то можно было бы использовать такое решение:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args','my_variation_attribute_options_args',10,1);
function my_variation_attribute_options_args($args){
 $args['show_option_none'] = 'Выбрать цвет';
 return $args;
}
```

Но мне нужно так же изменить текст и для варианта "выбрать размер" (а возможно и для других). А в случае выше поменяются ВСЕ "выбрать опцию" на этот вариант.
ID блоков цвета и размера имеют `id="pa_razmer"` и `id="pa_cvet"`

Т.е по сути нужно `$args['show_option_none'] = 'Выбрать цвет';` привязать к id нужного мне select.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/

Answer (score 0):

Строки перевода можно менять либо через хук `gettext` или через плагин `Loco Translate`.